# Android: Changing NFC settings (on/off) programmatically

Tags: android, settings, nfc

I trying to change NFC settings (on/off) programmatically on Android 2.3.3.

On the phone, under the "Wireless & network settings",
you can choose to set whether you want to use NFC to read and exchange tags or not.

So I would like to toggle this setting in my application.
But I can't seem to find an api for this.

I'm looking for some code that would probably look like this:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled( on/off );
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can not turn it `on/off` manually but you can send the user to the preferences if it is `off`:

```
    if (!nfcForegroundUtil.getNfc().isEnabled())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please activate NFC and press Back to return to the application!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
    }
```

Method `getNfc()` just returns the `nfcadapter`:

> nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext());

Comment: The if statement should be `mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);`     `if (mNfcAdapter.isEnabled())`

Comment: This answer is deprecated please also check below answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945100/android-changing-nfc-settings-on-off-programmatically/22559202#22559202

Comment: I think it is better to launch action android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS for new OS versions.

Answer (score 54):

It's not possible programatically without rooting device. 
But you can start `NFC Settings Activity` by intent action `Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS` for api level 16 and above. For api < 16 use `Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS`

Previous selected answer suggests to use `WIFI_SETTINGS` but we can directly move to `NFC_SETTINGS`

Here's the example :

```
android.nfc.NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter= android.nfc.NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(v.getContext());

            if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alertbox.setTitle("Info");
                alertbox.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_nfcon));
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Turn On", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                alertbox.show();

            }
```

Comment: NB - The `Settings` class is `android.provider.Settings`.

Comment: Which package for 'settings'? AS is giving me 8 choices. Always include imports.

Answer (score 9):

if you want to do it programmatically, apperently this Q holds the answer:

[How can I enable NFC reader via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509316/how-can-i-enable-nfc-reader-via-api)

**Edit**

it didn't hold the answer, but it held the key to the answer, on which I based my code I answered with in the Q.

I will paste it here as well in case anyone's interested.

I got it working through reflection

This code works on API 15, haven't checked it against other verions yet

```
public boolean changeNfcEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    // Turn NFC on/off
    final boolean desiredState = enabled;
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context);

    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
        // NFC is not supported
        return false;
    }

    new Thread("toggleNFC") {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting NFC enabled state to: " + desiredState);
            boolean success = false;
            Class<?> NfcManagerClass;
            Method setNfcEnabled, setNfcDisabled;
            boolean Nfc;
            if (desiredState) {
                try {
                    NfcManagerClass = Class.forName(mNfcAdapter.getClass().getName());
                    setNfcEnabled   = NfcManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("enable");
                    setNfcEnabled.setAccessible(true);
                    Nfc             = (Boolean) setNfcEnabled.invoke(mNfcAdapter);
                    success         = Nfc;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    NfcManagerClass = Class.forName(mNfcAdapter.getClass().getName());
                    setNfcDisabled  = NfcManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("disable");
                    setNfcDisabled.setAccessible(true);
                    Nfc             = (Boolean) setNfcDisabled.invoke(mNfcAdapter);
                    success         = Nfc;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                }
            }
            if (success) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully changed NFC enabled state to "+ desiredState);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error setting NFC enabled state to "+ desiredState);
            }
        }
    }.start();
    return false;
}//end method
```

This requires 2 permissions though, put them in the manifest:

```
 <!-- change NFC status toggle -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

The NFC button's state switches accordingly when the code is used, so there are no issues when doing it manually in the seetings menu.

---

**To clarify**: *This code doesn't work on normal devices. There are ways around, but at least it requires root*.

Comment: to clarify: this code doesn't work on normal devices. There are ways around, but at least it requires root.

Comment: I tried with this code, and create an application as a System App, but it doesn't work for me, in android kitkat.

Comment: Is there is any other way to interact with driver level to enable /disable nfc from android programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can control the NFC transfers and stuff. But for now turning it on and off is not possible :(

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was hoping we could turn it on and off. ><"

Comment: It used to be possible in Android 2.3 (before 2.3.6, I believe).

Answer (score -1):

Please check this below URL everything is given as step by step.

http://ranjithdroid.blogspot.com/2015/11/turn-onoff-android-nfc-by.html

Comment: Can you share the steps given in that link? You can still cite it, but if the link dies, this answer will be of little use.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. This is my blogspot link, I can ensure that it won't go future, because this is created in Google blog.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this solution requires the device to be **rooted**.