# Android library/API for NFC reader/writers

Tags: android, nfc, android-hardware

Are there any existing libraries that will allow an Android tablet (4.0.4) without a NFC chip to interface with an external USB NFC reader/writer?

Comment: It would have to be provided by the supplier of the "external USB NFC reader/writer", most likely.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the ACR 122 U can be connected via an USB OTG Cable. ACR has an Android test app on their [driver page](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=drivers&id=ACR122U). You will in addition need something like [NFC Tools for Java](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) to interact with the reader (sending commands etc).

Comment: I've developed a product which helps  you do this: https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api

Answer (score 0):

Maybe default packages will help you. Otherwise you can look for any third-party libs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html

or this may help you

[How can I enable NFC reader via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509316/how-can-i-enable-nfc-reader-via-api)

Answer (score 0):

ACR 1222L reader has its android library.

http://android.acs.com.hk/

The documentation of these libraries can be found here:

http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/5102/ACS-EVK-Android-112-A.zip